# Aceder à localização do ficheiro atual no .jrxml (Relatório Jasper)

Tags: jasper-reports, jasper, jaspersoft-studio

Boa tarde,

Estou a criar um relatório em Jasper que contém um sub-relatório (com Jaspersoft Studio). Para que este seja carregado, tenho de indicar a directoria do sub-relatório, que se encontra na mesma pasta que o do relatório pai. Neste momento, estou a utilizar o seguinte método no relatório pai:

```
        <subreport>
            <reportElement x="1" y="65" width="250" height="25" uuid="330b01bb-6d94-4644-b718-0fe59f69ce93"/>
            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
            <subreportExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\reports\\subreport_test.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
        </subreport>
```

Desta forma, ele consegue carregar. Funciona! No entanto, queria que fosse dinâmico: Ou seja, que o subreportExpression detetásse diretamente onde se encontra, e assim não teria de introduzir a localização 'hard-coded', como no código acima.

Pela pesquisa que fiz na Internet, pode ser usado o $P{SUBREPORT_DIR}, mas no meu caso dá-me null. Também tentei usar a seguinte expressão:

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA["subreport_test.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
```

Mas sem sucesso. Ele não consegue detetar onde está.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

eu uso o caminho relativo que se refere ao meu classpath dentro de um parametro como pode ser visto a baixo no meu parâmetro `$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}` é um parametro do tipo string que recebe como default o seguinte valor: `"br/com/blogspot/denisbenjamim/iReport/"` lembrando que a br é uma pasta dentro do diretorio src(classpath), os relatorios estão dentro da pasta iReport.

Eu empacoto meus `.jasper` dentro da aplicação e não fora em qualquer lugar , no seu caso no desktop na pasta report. Pelo o que vejo no caminho que esta descrito não esta dentro de um projeto mas fora em uma pasta.

```
<subreportExpression>
  <![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "Embarque_Relacao_subreport1.jasper"]]>
</subreportExpression>
```

Recomendo que empacote os .jasper dentro da sua aplicação e que fiquem no mesmo diretorio, conforme o exemplo que postei.

Para gerar o relatorio uso o seguinte metodo, onde o `getParametros()` retorna um objeto do tipo `Map`. Agora essa configuração se for distribuir para muitos clientes e claro terão locais diferentes eu recomendo o uso de um arquivo.properties o qual voce iria poder editar e mudar os valores dele assim como é um arquivo externo seria mais facil de modificar, eu costumava usar um arquivo deste na minha aplicação desktop para informar se queria ou não ver os parametros sql do Hibernate

```
    private JasperPrint geradorRelatorio() {
            try {
                fileVirtualizer.cleanup();
                getParametros().put(JRParameter.REPORT_VIRTUALIZER, fileVirtualizer);
                getParametros().put("SUBREPORT_DIR", "Aqui voce iria settar o caminho no seu cliente para o diretorio onde estaria o .jasper");
                if (conexao != null && dataSource == null) {
                    return JasperFillManager.fillReport(getStream(), getParametros(), getConecta());
                } else {
                    return JasperFillManager.fillReport(getStream(), getParametros(), getDataSource());
                }
            } catch (JRException |Relatorio_Exception  ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
            } 
            return null;
        }
```

Comment: Olá Denis, obrigado pela sua resposta. No entanto, o meu objetivo seria não colocar o diretório 'hard coded'. Queria que, de alguma forma, houvesse uma maneira de ter uma variável que detetásse o path onde se encontra o report, e aí sim, a partir daí, fazer o " <![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR} + "Embarque_Relacao_subreport1.jasper"]]>". Isto porque se trata de um projeto de um cliente. No meu localhost, o caminho para a pasta dos relatórios pode ser X, mas no cliente, o caminho é diferente, logo queria arranjar uma forma dinâmica de detetar onde se encontram os relatórios.

Comment: voce pode fazer isso meu caro quando voce informar um Map parametros por exemplo no seu meu caso se eu quise-se mudar o valor padrão do parametro $P{SUBREPORT_DIR} faria da seguinte forma: parametros.put("SUBREPORT_DIR","C:\\Users\\john\\Desktop\\reports\\");', editar minha resposta acima para ficar mais claro

Comment: Lembrando que no meu caso distribui minha aplicação por varias maquinas usando a tecnica do  relative patch que te falei acima nunca precisei mudar em computador de ninguem, por que o caminho não é o absoluto mas sim o relativo